# Convert date in varbinary encrypted column back to date

Tags: sql-server

I inserted this date '2022-12-01 after encrypting into a `varbinary` column DateAllowed.

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (Username, Password, UserType, DateAllowed)
VALUES ('Username', EncryptByKey(KEY_GUID('SymmetricKey'), 'Password'), EncryptByKey(KEY_GUID('SymmetricKey'), 'exampletext'), EncryptByKey(KEY_GUID('SymmetricKey'), '2022-12-01'));
```

It inserted successfully but when I select DateAllowed by decrypting and try to convert the decrypted text to date I get this error.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The query I used is below

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY RMSSQLSymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password';
SELECT CONVERT(date, DecryptByKey(DateAllowed)) AS 'DateAllowed1' FROM Tablename;
```

The interesting part is, if I use `varchar` I get the date  back

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(DateAllowed)) AS 'DateAllowed1' FROM Tablename;
```

The problem with this too is that when I get the date as varchar C# program I make in Visual Studio does not recognise as date datatype even if I try to convert it to DateTime.

How can I convert the Date that is in `varbinary` back to Date.

Comment: Why are you encrypting a date? Why not just store it in a `date` datatype?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to the problem.

I used a combination of `Parse` and `Convert` to get my date back.

Below is the query used.

```
SELECT PARSE (CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(DateAllowed)) AS date USING 'fr-FR') AS 'DateAllowed'  FROM Tablename;
```